# Creating multiple rows from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone, how can I use the following code to achieve as shown in the screenshot as shown above? So I would like it to be able to create new rows if it attempts to split the cells.

```
Sub SplitCellValue()
    Dim str As String
    Dim ArrStr() As String

    'Fill variables: str is the value of the active cell, ArrStr splits this value at the comma
    str = ActiveCell.Value
    ArrStr = Split(str, ", ")

    'Loop through each ArrStr to populate each cell below the activecell

    For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStr)
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ArrStr(i)
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Code looks good and I just tested with it working OK... What is the `ActiveCell` when you run your code though?

Comment: Hey Samuel! The activecell would be my selection of the cells. So I would choose the cell that contains one, two, three, four, five. And I'm looking for a way to split it by creating new rows for it.

Comment: Oh, so you want to actually insert a *new row* for each value (after the first)?

Comment: yes! like actual rows. So all other rows below **1** will be pushed below just as shown in screenshot

Comment: to add on, if you were to use the example as shown in my screenshot, the result won't be the 2nd picture. The results will be side by side. So for example, 1 will be with One, 2 with Two, etc.

Comment: Then, why you posted that second picture? We could messing things up on our own, too... :)

Comment: my apologies FaneDuru, I just want to show the outcome i'm hoping for. Thought it'll make the whole question clearer. I'm sorry if i caused any confusion..

Comment: No problem! We keep our neurons warmer... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. You also need to insert a row to each iteration. Omitting 0 array element you skip the first one:

```
Sub SplitCellValue()
    Dim str As String, actCell As Range, i As Long
    Dim ArrStr() As String
     Set actCell = ActiveCell 'it must be the cell with the comma separated string

     str = actCell.value
     ArrStr = Split(str, ", ")

    For i = UBound(ArrStr) To 1 Step -1
        actCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        actCell.Offset(1, 0).value = ArrStr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The variant after your last 'explanation'...

```
Sub SplitCellValue()
    Dim str As String, actCell As Range, i As Long
    Dim ArrStr() As String
     Set actCell = ActiveCell 'it must be the cell with the comma separated string

     str = actCell.value
     ArrStr = Split(str, ", ")
     If UBound(ArrStr) = 0 Then MsgBox _
       "Please select the cell keeping the comma separated string": Exit Sub
    actCell.value = ArrStr(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrStr)
        actCell.Offset(i, 0).value = ArrStr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Your code did not work because it updated each time the `ActiveCell`. It should be set from the beginning...

Comment: Hey FaneDuru, it works for the part at creating new rows! But the initial input **one, two, three, four, five** still remains in the original selected cells. Other wise, its great!

Comment: @Josh Ng: Adapted the code according to your last comment... But, it is not good to add pictures messing up the question meaning. We can mess up things on our own, too... :)

Comment: hey FaneDuru, I think i'm confusing you here, please pardon me. But I think my end output, i would want as per my updated screenshot! let me reupload again. so sorry.

Comment: @Josh Ng: Isn't it the answer you needed? Should I understand that neither your last comment does not clarify the issue?

Comment: With your 1st set of codes, I was able to get this instead: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV7Ie.png) I do not need the whole **one, two, three, four, five** paired to **1**, it should just be **one**.

Comment: @Josh Ng: Oh, yes. I adapted the code to rewrite the initial string. I kept it in order to use for some future tests if you will change your mind again... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212358/discussion-between-josh-ng-and-faneduru).

Comment: ahhh my apologies, i'm trying to mark the one that i'm going to use in my current project, i've marked back yours and its final. so sorry!

Comment: @Josh Ng: It is not a problem for me! I do not hunt votes! If the other one better serves your interest, feel free to make it the accepted answer. I wast just confused, having in mind our discussion...

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional `For...Next` loop within your existing one to add the rows. Include and `If` statement with a Boolean to determine if the rows are added or not (and thus if they need to be or not).

This will only insert a new row for the column of the active cell.

Something like:

```
'Loop through each ArrStr to populate each cell below the activecell
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim RowsAdded As Boolean

RowsAdded = False

For i = 0 To UBound(ArrStr)
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = ArrStr(i)
    If RowsAdded = False Then
        For y = 1 To UBound(ArrStr)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
        Next y
        RowsAdded = True
    End If
Next i
```

Here are images before and after code execution:

**Before:**

[image: Before code execution]

**After:**

[image: After code execution]

Comment: @Josh Ng I see a bit of confusion above, did my solution work as you intended?

Comment: hey samuel, I'm so sorry for the confusion. The results should be just as per my screen shot. So to create **new rows** below.

Comment: Ah Ok, `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlDown` will do the trick then

Comment: Thank you!!! it works. Everyone is so so helpful this far. I really appreciate it. I would go ahead and mark one of these answers as solved. Thank u!!

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer that you think *most* solved your issue or solved it *best*.

Comment: i'll go ahead and check FaneDuru's answer because i', going to use that as part of my project! Yours work great too, but i'll use it on another coming project instead. Thank you!!